# CSS is producing a box shadow not a drop shadow

Tags: css, google-chrome, drop-shadow

I have the image below and have written code in an external style sheet so that when you rollover the image it creates a drop shadow, however it is only creating a box shadow. The code I am using is:

[image]

```
.Pick:hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222); 
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The background of that image is not transparent. The drop-shadow is being applied to the background of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you posted isn't a transparent png...of course the shadow is going to be shown around the 'box-model'. Here, your ideal means of having a hover-shadow is to have 2 images and toggle between them on hover.

a real drop-shadow ( run snippet to see the effect ) ::

```css
.pick { width: 225px; height: 225px; background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/CeYiLOd.png');-o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s; }
.pick:hover { background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQGBI.png')}
```

```html
<div class="pick"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am just beginning to learn about CSS. Could I make the background transparent by editing it within photoshop?

Comment: Ah...fixed in photoshop. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your image needs to be a transparent PNG. If your image isn't transparent the shadow will be shown around the image.

I updated your png and it works here:

```css
.pick:hover {
   -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222); 
   filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222); }
```

```html
<img class="pick" src="http://i.imgur.com/CeYiLOd.png">
```

In order to accomplish this I opened it in Photoshop, and used the magic wand tool to select the white surrounding the image and deleted it.